# ansicon -i not working in Windows 7 x64

Tags: colors, cmd, windows-7-x64, ansicon

I have followed the direction on this site http://softkube.com/blog/ansi-command-line-colors-under-windows/ for downloading ansicon so I can have colored text in my command line. I run windows 7 on a 64-bit system. I extracted the downloaded zip files from my downloads directory into C:\ansicon. When I cd to the ansicon directory and type "ansicon -i" it responds with

'ansicon' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the instructions on that page are slightly misleading, the directory ansicon will contain one subdir for x86 (32 bits) and one for x64 (64 bits).

In a command window (<kbd>win</kbd>-<kbd>r</kbd>, cmd) go to

```
c:\ansicon\x64
```

and there execute

```
ansicon -i
```

Comment: Thank you! Your comment made me realize that when downloaded the files from the github site, for some reason they did not contain the x64 and x86 subdirectories. When I downloaded from the first link given, I saw these directories and was able to run "ansicon -i" correctly. Everything is nice and colored now, thanks a bunch my friend!

Comment: If the answer solves your problem may I kindly ask you to accept the answer?  Instructions can be found [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

The following steps should work well:

1. Download and unzip the latest version from https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/downloads
2. Open a command prompt and cd to the folder where you unzipped it
3. Now, cd into x64 and install it globally on your machine (For example, C:\ansicon\x64)
4. Type `ansicon.exe –i` OR `ansicon -i` and press Enter
5. Any program that prints ANSI colors will now display properly on your machine